# SQL Server edits the table name with dbo as prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I have been using SQL Server CE for a while. In that database the table names were like 
`UserPosts`, `UserProfile`.

But after my upgrade from SQL Server CE to SQL Server the names are edited to `dbo.UserPosts`, `dbo.UserProfile`. And also the names of columns are wrapped in square brackets like: `[UserProfile]`.

Why is this bracket used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets are used to surround names in SQL Server (they server the same purpose as double quotes).

For names that consist of alphanumeric characters and underscore, do not start with a digit, and are not reserved words, the square brackets are not needed.  They are typically used for columns that have "irregular" names, such as `[Column Name]` (note the space) or a reserved word like `[from]`.

When SQL Server generates code, it is overly conservative (in my opinion) about the use of square brackets.  It uses them for all column names, table names, and even type names in `create table` statements.  Because I never use "irregular" characters in my names, I find all the brackets to be unnecessary clutter.

The `dbo` is something called a schema.  SQL Server uses a three part naming convention for tables in a database:  ...  The database name defaults to the current data base, if it is not present.  The schema defaults to `dbo` (or another default schema if that has been changed, which is almost never).  And, there is a four part naming convention, where the first part is the server name.

Comment: I have also never used the brack, seems something excessive to me too; as I started my journey with SQL CE. The fourth is helpfull. Also, as much as I know is that the brackets are helpfull while having a column name such as `from, to`. They are wraped in brackets as `[from], [to]`.