# Adding dbo or Support in stores proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

A colleague of mine has given me a task to ensure all table name and pages in a stored procedure contains the relevant schemas?

For example if I have a table in a database that is `dbo.table1`,  then in a query if I have:

```
Select * from table1
```

He wants me to change it to:

```
Select * from dbo.table1
```

This is same for pages that start with Support.

What is the significance of adding in a scheme like `dbo.` At the start when manually writing SQL? Is it suppose to be better for performance as it seems to know where the tables even if I don't include .dbo at the start?

I'm using SQL server 2012 and its management studio.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not notice the performance if you write the schema in all of your queries. If you don't specify it, the engine will look through all of your schemas in your databases ( I'm not pretty sure if the engine will check the sys schemas too ) until it finds the table you're getting the data; It's recommended as a best practice to write it because you are telling to the engine what schema need to search the table.

I hope this answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

dbo is the schema which is used as part naming convention for tables in a mssql database

look at this post [SQL Server edits the table name with dbo as prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304142/sql-server-edits-the-table-name-with-dbo-as-prefix)